# Apparently defined object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I got this code:

```
var start = $('[name=start]').val();
var startCoordinates = $.getJSON('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=' + escape(start));

console.log(startCoordinates); 
// startCoordinates seems to be an object containing the object responseJSON.

startCoordinates = startCoordinates.responseJSON[0].geometry.location;
console.log(startCoordinates); 
// TypeError: startCoordinates.responseJSON is undefined
```

Why do I get a type error? `responseJSON` exists in the first log.

Comment: getJSON is asynchronous.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(startCoordinates);`?

Comment: Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: .ajax/w.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/w.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/w.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/w.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/w.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/w.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), ... }

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is that the `$.getJSON` function is asynchronous meaning that by the time you get to this line:

```
startCoordinates = startCoordinates.responseJSON[0].geometry.location;
```

the function has not been returned, meaning that `startCoordinates` is undefined.

However the `$.getJSON` has a callback function, `.done()` which is called when the response is successful.

```
var start = $('[name=start]').val();
$.getJSON('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=' + escape(start))
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // startCoordinates seems to be an object containing the object responseJSON.

        var result = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(result);
        // TypeError: startCoordinates.responseJSON is undefined

  });
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nevster/nr7j4ub5/6/) for an example.